# MathJax and the hover event

Tags: mathjax

I'm finding MathJax a superior alternative to MathML.  However, I'm having some trouble getting MathJax to render while using a `:hover` event in my CSS:

```
span.rollover span {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: navy;
  font: 1em "Computer Modern", "Computer Modern Roman", "Latin Modern", "Cambria Math", serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 150%;
}
span.rollover:hover span {
  display: initial;
  top: -30px;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

At the moment it's displaying garbage; a current draft of the page can be found [here](http://pages.suddenlink.net/physics/amp/amp.htm).  Here's an example of the problem:

```
<span class="rollover">Initial angle<span>0.0 &le; $\theta_0$ &le; 1.6 rad</span></span>
```

Is there a way to force MathJax to render the markup for such an event?

Comment: If you look at the code after MathJax runs you see there is a `<script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-3">E = \frac{1}{2} m L^2 \omega^2 + m g L (1 - \cos \theta)</script>` tag. With the source in it. A bit of javascript should be able to detect the hover event and pop up the tex. Note with MathJax you can always right-click on an equation which bring up a menu allowing you to see the source.

Comment: In your <span> there is no delimiters around the equation. Maybe just use the normal maths delimiters your using in the rest of the document say `<span class="rollover">Initial angle $0.0 &le; $\theta_0$ &le; 1.6 rad$</span>` using $ as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is too aggressive: it applies to *every* span within your rollover spans.  Since MathJax uses spans to lay out the mathematics, it applies to those, and so you are forcing the `position`, `border`, `top`, etc. for every element used by MathJax.  That means you are moving the math content out of place, and giving it borders, and so on (this account for some of the extra elements that appear above the ones you expect.

If you change

```
span.rollover span {
  ...
}

span.rollover:hover span {
  ...
}
```

to

```
span.rollover > span {
  ...
}

span.rollover:hover > span {
  ...
}
```

so that these styles only apply to the *top-level* child spans (rather than *every* span), that should do it for you.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I have been struggling with this for so long. Thank you for contributing your understanding of this problem.